# Phone symbol/ Website logo in XeLatex

Tags: fonts, hyperref, symbols, packages, pdf

`\texttt{ÔÑã}~\href{tel:\myphone}{\myphone}\\`  produce a mobile icon 
on the pdf file and this one 
`href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\myweb} {\texttt{ÔÇå}~\myweb}` generate the little nice Linkedin logo beside the url.

Can anyone please tell me how the special character inside the `textttt{}`are referring those icon and logo?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share with us how you obtained these? I can't replicate your input-output...

Answer (score 3):

`ÔÑã` and `ÔÇå` are Unicode code points, viewed in mac roman encoding:

`ÔÑã`: 0xEF, 0x84, 0x8B -> U+F10B
`ÔÇå`: 0xEF, 0x82, 0x8C -> U+F08C

The Unicode block is the private area. Font Awesome uses this area for its symbols:

U+F10B: `\faMobile` or `\faicon{mobile}`
U+F08C: `\faLinkedinSquare` or `\faicon{linkedin-square}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\begin{document}
\faMobile/\faicon{mobile} and \faLinkedinSquare/\faicon{linkedin-square}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]